Why getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter()
I have installed ColdFusion 2021 with FusionReactor in the cloud infrastructure.
FusionReactor shows a 500 error with the below-mentioned stack trace for a specific URL when the URL is called from a scheduled job from an Azure Logic App.
The error summarises that I am getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in MonitoringServletFilter class at line number 74.
FusionReactor shows this strange trace:
javax.servlet.ServletException:
ROOT CAUSE: 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:74)
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:47)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
coldfusion.inspect.weinre.MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.doFilter(MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.java:57)
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:47)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor171.invoke(Unknown source)
jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filterchain.WrappedFilterChain.doFilter(WrappedFilterChain.java:134)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doNext(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:698)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doHttpServletRequest(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:256)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doFusionRequest(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:119)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.handle(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:736)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorCoreFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorCoreFilter.java:36)
jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor170.invoke(Unknown source)
jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filterchain.WrappedFilterChain.doFilter(WrappedFilterChain.java:71)
jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor172.invoke(Unknown source)
jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.agent.filter.FusionReactorStaticFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorStaticFilter.java:54)
com.intergral.fusionreactor.agent.pointcuts.NewFilterChainPointCut$1.invoke(NewFilterChainPointCut.java:50)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:545)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:355)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:450)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

But once I manually run the same URL, it returns 200.
What can be the possible reason?

Hello Sushovan, you can edit your question, and add the MonitoringServletFilter class, highlighting the "74" line?.
